# How do you modify databases in a webapp that is already running & constantly modified? Especially in a team environment?

Tags: database, postgresql, react-fullstack

**How do you work on existing web app databases that constantly get modified in realtime**

Let's assume you have a react application with postgres as your database. The App is an ecommerce website that stores user data and their shop orders.

In a scenario like this the database gets constantly modified (by users registering, new orders).

How do you work on existing databases in a professional environment when you work in a team when the database gets modified in realtime?

***Solutions I've thought about***

Do you create a staging database, like a copy of your postgres database and have it under version control? How would this workflow look like? You push your changes to a git repo that is connected to the database that then migrates the changes with your live db (without touching new data?)

I have practical experience in working with Git & a general understanding of docker(if this helps), but as soon as I add databases to my projects I've no clue how teams handle version control & realtime database changes.

Can someone explain to me how they do it in their apps while working in a team of multiple devs? Any external resource that teaches this concept (I only find general version control tutorials) is highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "work on existing databases"?  Do you mean schema changes, i.e. adding new tables, and adding new columns to old tables?

Comment: By doing anything with the database (adding data, modifying tables, schemas) etc. I'm talking about the general concept of working with a database that is beeing actively used.

Comment: Adding data (i.e. adding new rows to an existing table) to a busy database is perfectly normal.  It shouldn't be any problem at all.  Please explain what actual problems you are having.